# how to load Windows unity3d licence into Mac machine?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I have Unity3d pro licence for windows and i want to use that windows licence in to Mac so how can i use it in my Mac. I know that i can export my licence but the problem is that when i export my licence from windows machine it's extension is .alf while my mac machine only accept .ulf. can anybody help me?

Comment: Not a direct solution, but you can email Unity3D and their response time is pretty good. Provide proof of your account credentials and they'll likely provide instructions to do so, if not the license file itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same license on two machines (maximum).
Basically download Unity on your mac and activate using your serial number.
if you want to actually "Move" the license (i.e. you replaced your machine) then better to contact unity directly.